# Colocação dos adjetivos possessivos

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas, mudanças-históricas, determinantes-possessivos

Obviamente, há duas construções mais comuns para a colocação dos adjetivos possessivos.  Se é definido antes, indefinido depois.  (E sem artigo, passa a ser determinador, e então definido.)

- o meu amigo
- um amigo meu

Às vezes encontro com a colocação inversa:

- o amigo meu
- um meu amigo

A primeira soa-me mais antiga (talvez só por influência doutras línguas), mas a segunda, é considerada aceitável, antiga, incorreta ou talvez particular a um dialeto?

Comment: Qual é a pergunta, ou dúvida, em concreto? Parece-me pouco claro, um bocado abstrato.

Comment: "um meu amigo" é relativamente comum. "O amigo meu" nem tanto, mas também é possível: "o pão nosso de cada dia".

Answer (score 2):

Vejamos o que diz Celso Cunha na Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo (1984):

> O `pronome adjectivo possessivo` precede normalmente o substantivo que determina [...].
>   Pode, no entanto, vir posposto ao substantivo:
>
> 1. Quando este vem desacompanhado de artigo definido:
>
>    - Esperava **notícias tuas** para de novo te escrever. (António Nobre, *CI*, 119.)
>    - Soube por José Veríssimo que estranhou a ausência de **cartas minhas**. (Euclides da Cunha, *OC*, II, 707.)

Nestes exemplos, não se pode antepor o pronome sem alterar o significado. Esta frase:

> Esperava **tuas notícias** para de novo te escrever.

é equivalente a estoutra, muito mais frequente no Português moderno de Portugal.

> Esperava **as tuas notícias** para de novo te escrever.

A diferença é a mesma entre "esperar notícias" e "esperar *as* notícias", portanto se são notícias específicas ou não.

Há ainda expressões mais ou menos fixas usadas sem artigo nas quais seria muito estranho antepor o pronome como "Isso é impressão tua/problema teu."

Continuando:

> 2. quando o substantivo já está determinado (pelo artigo indefinido ou por numeral, por pronome demonstrativo ou por pronome indefinido):
>
>    - Recebi, no Rio, no dia da posse no Instituto, **um telegrama seu**, de felicitações... (Euclides da Cunha, *OC*, II, 639.)
>    - Note **este erro seu**: não há em mim (que eu seja consciente) o menor espírito de renúnica ou de esquecimento de mim próprio. (Jackson de Figueiredo, *C*, 177.)
>    - Como tu foste infiel
>        A **certas ideias minhas**! (Fernando Pessoa, *QGP*, 83.)

Aqui, "este erro seu" é facilmente substituído por "este seu erro", que é de resto muito mais comum (encontrei duas ordens de grandeza no CETEMPúblico, o que até acho estranho).

"Certas ideias minhas" é também muito mais comum do que "certas minhas ideias", construção para a qual de resto só encontrei uma entrada (contra 12 da outra) no CETEMPúblico:

> [...]  facto que decorre do alcance da sua arquitectura metafórica, de um **certo seu gosto** pelas sinestesias ou [...]

Por fim, com o artigo indefinido ou numeral, a posposição é mais comum, especialmente na oralidade. No CETEMPúblico, a diferença na frequência das duas formas é pouco marcada (mas com uma vantagem para a posposição). Exemplo:

> O assaltante entregou parte do produto do roubo a **um seu amigo, Mário**, de 21 anos, para que este lhe comprasse heroína.

Adiante:

> 3. nas interrogações directas:
>
>    - Onde estais, **cuidados meus**? (Manuel Bandeira, *PP*, 23.)
>    - Mas dize: esta amaríssima tristeza
>        Terá vindo em verdade das **mãos tuas**? (Eugénio de Castro, *UV*, 18.)
>    - Em todo o caso... Agora ouve-se menos ou é apenas uma **impressão minha**? (Augusto Abelaira, *NC*, 15.)

O último exemplo é estranho, porque é indistinguível de 2. e porque "impressão minha/tua/etc." é uma expressão fixa que geralmente se usa sem artigo, como referido antes. As outras duas inversões são típicas da literatura.

> 4. quando há ênfase:
>
>    - — Tu não lustras as unhas! tu trabalhas! tu és digna **filha minha**! pobre, mas honesta! (Machado de Assis, *OC*, I, 672.)
>    - — Ninguém, **senhores meus**, que empreenda uma jornada extraordinária, [...] (Rui Barbosa, *EDS*, 685.)
>    - — Já lá se vão trinta anos, **Deus meu**! (Augusto Frederico Schmidt, *GB*, 111.)

Este tipo de inversões são um pouco retóricas, mas são usadas.

O que não figura nestes exemplos é um caso com um artigo definido como tu dás ("o amigo meu"), mas a construção também é possível. O CETEMPúblico tem vários exemplos. As mais comuns são expressões do género "o *X* nosso de cada dia", onde *X* geralmente é "pão":

> - [...] devido ao malefício dessas coisas mesquinhas que são **o pão nosso de cada dia** nas províncias mais incultas.
> - Que mal me senti a fazer de crítico em causa própria, agora que a guerra das audiências tem sido arma e álibi para desvalorizar a função daqueles que se obrigam profissionalmente a fazer aquilo que para milhões é **o prazer nosso de cada dia** -- ver televisão.
> - Novo agitar de águas pela euforia desagregada do PRD e, para cumprir **a sina sua**, Cavaco galga as ondas.

Por fim, voltando a citar:

> A alternância de colocações presta-se a efeitos estilísticos, como nos mostra este exemplo:
>     És **meu** único **desejo**,
>       Ah! fosse o **desejo teu**! (Guimarães Passos, *VS*, 24.)

Answer (score 1):

Nada impede que tu fales "o amigo meu" ou "um meu amigo". **No Brasil ninguém diria que é errado, mas não é o modo como nos expressamos.**  Da mesma forma, não dizemos "as filhas minhas" ou "uma minha conquista".  Este último, por sinal, além de unusual forma um belo cacófato. Já "o amigo meu", se falado rapidamente, será confundido com "um amigo meu".

Answer (score 1):

[***Um meu amigo*** é aceite](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/regra-para-a-posicao-dos-pronomes-possessivos/29320) mas muito menos usado que ***um amigo meu***:

> **Um meu amigo** chinês, quando passeávamos ambos pelas ruas de Pequim, exclamou de repente com entusiasmada veemência: "Olhe um asno!" ([Armindo Trevisan](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armindo_Trevisan), [*Como Apreciar a Arte*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KbayWtpYvrcC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=%22um%20meu%20amigo%22&source=bl&ots=hTqVNZdJC9&sig=8mT8UCWtW1YY0fcSKKg-8ZP7JpY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBjgKahUKEwikj4bcqOPIAhUJOxQKHVr0Cu0#v=onepage&q=%22um%20meu%20amigo%22&f=false), 1990, p. 74.)
>
> **Uma minha amiga** me disse que, ao comprar uma camisinha para mim no Oriente Médio, só havia homens na fila... ([Minha avó deu a primeira, conta colecionador com mais de 1.200 camisinhas](http://noticias.uol.com.br/tabloide/ultimas-noticias/tabloideanas/2015/09/28/minha-avo-deu-a-primeira-conta-colecionador-com-mais-de-1200-camisinhas.htm), uol notícias, 2015.)

Por outro lado, ***o amigo meu*** só me parece razoável em frases como:

> **O amigo meu que** conheceste no sábado pediu-me o teu número de telefone.
>
> **A colega minha com quem** simpatizaste também gostou de ti.
>
> Marcelo, **o amigo meu que** mais se divertiu, tomou do apetrecho... ([*Repórter descreve bastidores de sex club*](http://acapa.virgula.uol.com.br/mobile/noticia.asp?codigo=6860) in A CAPA, 2009.)
>
> Pode elogiá-lo à vontade, dizer que **o amigo meu que** o indicou acha que ele é gênio e outras qualidades altas. ([João António](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%A3o_Ant%C3%B4nio_Ferreira_Filho#Bibliografia), [*Carta aos Amigos Caio Porfírio Carneiro e Fábio Lucas*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9o5XApihZGUC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=%22o%20amigo%20meu%20que%22%20-mamando&source=bl&ots=erzXHSWWaF&sig=7odbEzRGYaSepTl9HhV24ZxOHNI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMIo9OpjqvjyAIVx9saCh2PGAPp#v=onepage&q=%22o%20amigo%20meu%20que%22%20-mamando&f=false), 2005.)

Mas ninguém diria *o amigo meu João*... ou *a casa minha está à tua disposição*. A construção ***amigo meu***, sem artigo, é idiomática, mas significa *qualquer amigo meu*:

> Amigo meu que venha a Setúbal ficará em minha casa.
> Filha minha não namoraria com aquele traste.

Depois há, claro, [a poesia, onde regras e convenções pesam menos.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ly6Vq1-rMGs)

Comment: Estou para saber porque é que o link da "Carta aos..." exclui o termo "mamando" :p

Comment: Que o d'A CAPA o exclua é que é verdadeiramente admirável :)